# How to differentiate online IP Address from Local IP/Other Machine IP on LAN in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any possible way to differentiate online IP Address from Local/Other Machine IP on LAN in Java?

I am working on a application, there is a need to identify the Local IP/LAN IP and Online IP address input by user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not very clear, you want to get the LAN IP of a machine from an outside WAN? If that is so, you can't; when you are using NAT you only see the external IP.

Comment: No, I need to know how to make differentiate between online & offline IP Address working from a application to work on both online & offline. User just provide the IP, name & password.

Comment: You have to check this by the subnet of the IP address and compare it against your host's IP address. If it is in the same subnet, then that IP address is in the same local subnet as yours. Otherwise, it is on the remote subnet. What do you mean by online and offline, anyway?

Comment: @Kishore but why do you want to differentiate? What different behaviour do you need for LAN and WAN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to do this based solely on the IP (and that is not specific to Java, but based on the way networks work).

If you have additional information, however, you may be able to do this. There are three networks of IP addresses that are not used on the internet. Those are:

```
10.0.0.0/8
172.16.0.0/12
192.168.0.0/16
```

If you know the LAN IP addresses will be from specific ranges (including the network the host is in on which your application is runnning), you can differentiate; however - and do not try this at home kids since it will give you headaches - if you use IP addresses in your LAN that are also used on the internet, you will not only have address conflicts, but also trouble to distinguish between online and LAN IPs.

---

Something else though; if your users try to "connect" via the internet, but are behind a NAT, your application will only see the source of their traffic as the public IP of the gateway doing the NAT for your users. So, for example, if two of your users are somewhere in a LAN with IPs from 10.0.1.0/24, but their gateway has a public IP of 123.123.123.123, your application will see BOTH users as having the IP 123.123.123.123

You might have to come up with a different way of authentication if you intend to use this in a way similar to VPN, or you have to know all the public IPs of all gateways of all of your users who are behind NATs.

---

A note on terminology, as Marcelo pointed out: afaik, "online" and "offline" are not terms usually used with IPs. We rather speak of "public" (the ones seen on the internet) and "private" IPs (those within your own network noone on the internet can see).

Comment: IMO it's even better to say "LAN address" and "WAN address". As for the question, the only way to distinguish LAN addresses is to check for them being in those three ranges G. Bach specified.

Comment: LAN and WAN are probably used with the meaning Kishore described; strictly speaking though I think that is not the appropriate use, since you can have a private WAN as well. It would be expensive and overkill to have one, but IMO, WAN is not synonymous with public and LAN isn't with private. I also somewhat dislike the terms WAN and LAN since they're vague and don't hint at the fact that there may be access barriers besides an internet connection. But those are problems I have with these terms personally; in the community, they may be more widespread than private and public

Comment: True, there can also be one or more WANs between the user's LAN and the Internet: Italy's largest highspeed ISP uses one such WAN (which of course creates lots of problem for P2P and gaming, but I digress); is not impossible (for example in a university) to have nested LANs. That's why I asked him why exactly does he need to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the external IP using some API such as `http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp`. If you can reach that API and get the IP, you are "online" - i.e., connected to the internet. If you can't, you are "offline" (unless the host is down, etc).

If you need the local host, you can use

```
InetAddress thisIp =InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println("IP:"+thisIp.getHostAddress())
```

Please clarify what you consider an "offline IP address", as I've never heard of such concept before.

Comment: Care to give reasons for the downvote? I can't see what Marcelo said wrong.